# _NSCFConstantString latitude]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: objective-c, nscfstring

```
for(int i=0;i<[self.printers count]; i++)
    {
        PublicPrivateEvent *printerselection = [printers objectAtIndex:i];

        CGFloat latt = [printerselection.latitude floatValue]; //Here is broken
        CGFloat lng=[printerselection.longtitude floatValue];
         pointsCoOrds[index++] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latt,lng);

    }
```

Hi All,
Im trying to get the value from PublicPrivateEvent class. But I dont know for what I cant handle it? I have this problem: _NSCFConstantString latitude]: unrecognized selector sent to instance .. DO you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `printers` contains `NSString`s and not `PublicPrivateEvent`s.

Comment: @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *latitude;

In publicprivateEvent I have latitude as NSString?  So i didnt understand what do you mean?

Comment: I was not talking about `latitude`. Read my comment again.

Comment: I read. But I couldnt understand what do you mean?

Comment: Show us how the `printers` array is create.

Comment: I have my printersArray in previous viewcontroller, and Im trying to send this array to other viewcontroller

  eventmap.printers=[xmlEventParser getprinters];

like this I am transferring.